# How to convert List<Event> to Map<DateTime, List<Event>> in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I want to convert List to Map in Dart as follows. Is there any good method for this?

```dart
class Event {
  const Event(this.date, this.title);
  final DateTime date;
  final String title;
}

List<Event> eventList = [
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "buy milk"),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "go to gym"),
  Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 2), "running"),
];

// I want to convert map as follows.

Map<DateTime, List<Event>> eventDayMap = {
  DateTime(2021, 1, 1): [Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "buy milk"), Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 1), "go to gym")],
  DateTime(2021, 1, 2): [Event(DateTime(2021, 1, 2), "running")]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each `DateTime` stores only dates and no times, I would use `??=` to add an empty list by default for each date, and then I'd just append list elements:

```dart
var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
for (var event in eventList) {
  (eventDayMap[event.date] ??= []).add(event);
}
```

If you are storing time information but want to index by date, then you would have to normalize the key first:

```dart
DateTime dateOnly(DateTime dateTime) {
  if (dateTime.isUtc) {
    return DateTime.utc(dateTime.year, dateTime.month, dateTime.day);
  } else {
    return DateTime(dateTime.year, dateTme.month, dateTime.day);
  }
}

var eventDayMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
for (var event in eventList) {
  (eventDayMap[dateOnly(event.date)] ??= []).add(event);
}
```

and if you then wanted the events sorted by time:

```dart
for (var list in eventDayMap.values) {
  list.sort((event1, event2) => event1.date.compareTo(event2.date));
}
```